# sendMultipartTextMessage sending as multiple SMS messages?

Tags: java, android, sms, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I am sending long SMS messages in Android using the following code:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

The problem is that on phones pre Lollipop 5.0 (mainly noticed on Kitkat 4.4) the SMS is being sent as two separate SMS rather than a joined (multipart) message.

On phones that are running Lollipop 5.0+ the message is correctly sent as a long SMS?

I have tested this on two exact same model phones one running 4.4 Kitkat and the other updated with 5.0 Lollipop and the same behaviour described above occurs? Has anyone else noticed this or found a resolution?

Comment: Does your carrier in both lollipop and kitkat is same?

Comment: @Lrrr Yes they are both on O2 UK

Comment: @Apqu this code works fine on Android 6.0 and Samsung A5 and S7, however, in my sending phone, I always see two the same messages, one unsent and another one sent. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a message is long enough, typically more than 160 characters, it's sent as separate SMS messages, and on GSM networks a bit of extra meta data is added called a User Data Header (UDH) that tells the receiver that the separate messages should be combined.

What you want to happen is for the receiver to combine them back into a single message. Note that it's the **receiver** that combines them, so that's where you need to be looking. As far as I know, the behaviour of sendMultipartTextMessage in Lollipop is the same as in KitKat.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the pointer on UDH, I think this may be causing issues, looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header now :-)

Answer (score 2):

> "The maximum length of each SMS text message can vary by carrier, but are typically limited to 160 characters. As a result longer messages need to be broken into series of smaller parts. The `SmsManager` includes the `divideMessage()` method, which accepts a string as an input and breaks it into an `ArrayList` of messages, wherein each part is less than the maximum allowable size.
>
> We can then use `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method on the `SmsManager` to transmit the array of messages..."

Taken from: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/10/send-multiparttextmessge-in-android.html?m=1

Comment: @Tur Does my answer is OK for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I try sendMultipartTextMessage but it still sends the messages as multiple single message rather than combining the array into a long multipart message?

Comment: @Tur Does your SMS message is longer than 160 characters?

Comment: Yes but sendMultipartTextMessage is intended to rejoin these messages during the sending process (as it does on Lollipop) it seems that on KitKat it does not rejoin the messages.

Comment: @Tur I don't know a lot about it. I used this method once and it send my long message as 3 parts on Lollipop and KitKat.